# Reading specific columns from excel and parsing the data

Tags: excel, clojure

As records are immutable i am unable to read in the data and parse it without it making a new instance of itself. Moreover, how would i be able to read my excel files from a number of specific columns instead of reading from column 0 to EOF. Is there anyway where i could read in the data from say column 1, column 3, column 5. Supposedly, Column 1 would be parsed as a string, Column 3 as an integer and Column 5 as a long.

```
(defrecord Record [Name Age Index])

(defn read-csv [fname count]
  (with-open [file (io/reader fname)]
    (doall (take count (map (comp first csv/read-csv)
                            (line-seq file))))))
(def records (map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "C:/Users/user/Documents/URECA/hi/lib/test.csv" 1)))
```

This is what i have but it seems to read the columns incrementally

Comment: Perhaps the approach described [at this site](http://drknucklehead.wordpress.com/tag/clojure-csv/) might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep quotes of text fields you can parse csv file by regexp:

```
(defn read-csv [fname count]
  (with-open [file (io/reader fname)]
    (doall (map #(str/split % #",") ; doesn't work with commas in text fields
                (take count (line-seq file))))))

(defn make-record [idxs types row]
  (apply ->Record
         (map (fn [idx t]
                (let [value (nth row idx)]
                  (case t
                    :string value
                    :int (Integer/parseInt value)
                    :long (Long/parseLong value))))
              idxs types)))

(def records (map (partial make-record
                           [0 2 4]
                           [:string :int :long])
                  (read-csv "/home/mobyte/test.csv" 3)))

(pprint records)
-> ({:Name "\"s1\"", :Age 1, :Index 111}
    {:Name "\"s2\"", :Age 2, :Index 112}
    {:Name "\"s3\"", :Age 3, :Index 113})

(type (:Age (first records)))
->java.lang.Integer

(type (:Index (first records)))
-> java.lang.Long

(type (:Name (first records)))
-> java.lang.String
```

Comment: Could you explain the records part as i am not too sure what it is about. Perhaps more comments would be appreciated in terms of the fn [row] as i cant seem to see any input for the row part. It would be considered as a nested function i suppose

Comment: I've updated the post. Now nested part is in the separate function `make-record`.